# How do I verify and count the presence of specific data in an associative array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, arraylist

I have a question about manipulating data in an associative array.

#### What I want to do

I want to verify if an order exists in sellingItems.

#### Background(why?)

I want to check if there is an order to return the number of products in stock as a response.

#### Question

I want to check if a specific data (order) exists in an associative array and calculate the inventory count.

```
  public calculateStockQuantity(itemInstances) {
    const stockQuantity = //We want to count the number of items in stock. In this case, we want it to be 2 (calculated based on whether the data exists in sellingItem.order or not).)
　  return stockQuantity;
  }
```

#### Associative array of targets

//There are three itemInstances for one product because the number of products sold is three.

```
itemInstances =
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "sellingItem": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "price": 3000,
                "orderedItem": [
                    {
                        "id": 1
　　　　　　　　　　　　　   "ordered_at": "2021-04-01 10:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "sellingItem": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "price": 3000,
                "orderedItem": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "sellingItem": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "price": 3000,
                "orderedItem": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Sorry for asking like a newbie.

Comment: Looks like your array is not consistent. Should it be sometime `order` and other time `orderItem`?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the sequence description. They are all orderItem. The question text has also been corrected. Thank you.

Comment: You can use a Set data structure to select only unique data

Comment: Sorry, but neither the question nor the data-structure is entirely clear to me. I assume that you have an issue that there are nested arrays, so let's flatten that first: `const orderedItems = itemInstances.flatMap(item => item.sellingItem).flatMap(sellingItem => sellingItem.orderedItem);` Maybe this is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is something you are looking for, assuming if `orderedItem` array is empty then that `sellingItem` will be counted as `in stock`

```
let count = itemInstances.filter(({sellingItem : [{ orderedItem }]}) => orderedItem.length === 0).length;

console.log(count); //return 2 based on question data
```